# Performance Tricks for C# Logging

Tags: c#, performance, logging

I am looking into C# logging and I do not want my log messages to spend any time processing if the message is below the logging threshold.  The best I can see log4net does is a threshold check AFTER evaluating the log parameters.

Example:

```
_logger.Debug( "My complicated log message " + thisFunctionTakesALongTime() + " will take a long time" )
```

Even if the threshold is above Debug, thisFunctionTakesALongTime will still be evaluated.

In log4net you are supposed to use _logger.isDebugEnabled so you end up with

```
if( _logger.isDebugEnabled )
    _logger.Debug( "Much faster" )
```

I want to know if there is a better solution for .net logging that does not involve a check each time I want to log.

In C++ I am allowed to do

```
LOG_DEBUG( "My complicated log message " + thisFunctionTakesALongTime() + " will take no time" )
```

since my LOG_DEBUG macro does the log level check itself.  This frees me to have a 1 line log message throughout my app which I greatly prefer.  Anyone know of a way to replicate this behavior in C#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can target .NET 3.5 (C# 3.0) you can use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to wrap the `if` statements.

so you can do the equivalent "macro":

```
logger.Log_Debug("Much faster");

logger.Log_Debug(() => { "My complicated log message " + thisFunctionTakesALongTime() + " will take no time" });
```

by wrapping the check in this method:

```
public class Log4NetExtensionMethods {
    // simple string wrapper
    public void Log_Debug(this log4net.ILog logger, string logMessage) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled) {
             logger.Debug(logMessage);
        }
    }

    // this takes a delegate so you can delay execution
    // of a function call until you've determined it's necessary
    public void Log_Debug(this log4net.ILog logger, Func<string> logMessageDelegate) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled) {
             logger.Debug(logMessageDelegate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I am evaluating functions to get the log message, wouldnt this be just as slow?  I want to avoid all function evaluations if the log level is below my threshold.

Comment: You're correct that you'll need to delay the function evaluation. See my update that uses an anonymous delegate.

Comment: D'oh, that was my answer too.  I should warn you that if you're looking for speed, you do not want to use delegates.  You should just take the hit and use if `if (logger.isDebugEnabled)` around anything expensive.  There is no solution which is both performant and elegant.

Comment: @bobbymcr: Performant is relative. Delegate invocation is on the same level as any inteface function call, where `thisFunctionTakesALongTime()` could run a Monte Carlo simulation that takes days.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm referring to the performance between using a delegate for conditional evaluation vs. a simple boolean check.  See my answer below -- it's a 20%+ performance hit for using the lambda when logging is not enabled.  The simple rule is if performance is critical, do not use late binding.

Answer (score 3):

17.4.2 The Conditional attribute

The attribute Conditional enables the definition of conditional methods. The Conditional attribute indicates a condition by testing a conditional compilation symbol. Calls to a conditional method are either included or omitted depending on whether this symbol is defined at the point of the call. If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call (including evaluation of the parameters of the call) is omitted.

```
[ Conditional("DEBUG") ]
public static void LogLine(string msg,string detail)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log: {0} = {1}",msg,detail);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Total = 0;
    for(int Lp = 1; Lp < 10; Lp++)
    {
        LogLine("Total",Total.ToString());
        Total = Total + Lp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I will do some more research on it.
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I would assume that the better logging libraries already use this technique.

Comment: just because you're calling a "logger.debug" method doesn't mean you're actually running in debug mode. The name "debug" is really just method name for an arbitrary threshold as defined by the application developer. I would be surprised if Log4Net, EnterpriseLibrary, etc... actually use any conditional attributes since the attribute relies on the presence of a compilation symbol.

Comment: Create two versions of the log method - with and without conditional compilation, i.e. LogLine() and LogLineConditional(), so you can choose which one to use, e.g. use LogLineConditional() in performance sensitive areas. Also useful to use a conditional string that is _not_ "DEBUG" so this can be controlled separately from the DEBUG build.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that all method parameters must be evaluated before the method is invoked.  There is no way around this, given the syntax you are using.  Since C# does not have a real preprocessor or macros, you can't do anything like "LOG_DEBUG".  The best you could do is use `if (logger.isDebugEnable)` as suggested.

The only thing I can think of is maybe using something like a lambda expression to delay evaluation.  But I would warn you that **this will almost certainly have more of a performance hit in the end**.

```
internal class Sample
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DelayedEvaluationLogger.Debug(logger, () => "This is " + Expensive() + " to log.");
    }

    private static string Expensive()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

internal static class DelayedEvaluationLogger
{
    public static void Debug(ILog logger, Func<string> logString)
    {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled)
        {
            logger.Debug(logString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are lambda expressions that expensive?

Comment: @Charles: lambdas are relatively inexpensive as far as late binding goes, but far more expensive than a boolean check and a method call. In my simple test over a billion iterations (code here: http://pastebin.com/aRtMtsxz ), I measured about 25% overhead for lambda vs. boolean check when logging was not enabled. With a cached lambda (save the lambda to a field so it doesn't get re-generated each time), there is slightly less overhead (a litter under 20%).

Answer (score -1):

Without a preprocessor you're SOL. Of course there's nothing preventing you from using one before feeding your code to the C# compiler.

Comment: anonymous delegates and extra classes - wow that's a lot of typing.